# read sql cel, find row ID and update cell in same row

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

In my C# program i want it to read a column, and find the value i return, then return to me the row id so i can write in another cell in that row. So if my parameter is "Test" for my method, it will run a query (thats what i need) and find "Test" and return a row id so i can update another cell in that row. 
Like this: (say this is my sql table)

```
   Text    |Integer
1 "stuff"  |2
2 "Test"   |5
3 "other"  |7
4 "stuf"   |1
```

I would want it to find row 2 so i can update 5 as the integer. Thanks in advance. Tell me if you can't completely understand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one go

```sql
UPDATE table1 
   SET int_field = 5 
 WHERE text_field = 'Test';
```

That's assuming that `text_field` has `UNIQUE` index defined for it. Otherwise it will update all records where textfield = 'Test'. And apparently you don't have UNIQUE index on that column since two records 1 and 4 have text_field set to 'stuff'.

But if you for some reason need to get an id and if you have that column defined then simple select will do the trick

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM table1
 WHERE text_field = 'Test';
```

Comment: @user2374093 You're welcome. Glad it helped. But be aware of and deal appropriately with entries that have duplicate values in text field. Good luck.